# Model-view design in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, model-view-controller

I'm creating a simple game to learn Flash programming.  To have a clean model/view separation, I want to create a Player class which simply holds data relevant to the user.  I'm also creating a StatusView class which extends MovieClip and which coresponds to a movie clip symbol which I've created in my Flash project.  Basically the StatusView will display the data of my Player class onscreen.

I'm used to doing this sort of thing using listeners, so I've found the EventDispatcher class and added one as a member of my Player class.  I'd like to have my StatusView movie clip add an event listener to my Player class so that it can receive messages whenever I change the data in my Player class.

The problem is, there doesn't seem to be anywhere for me to put my Player class so that the StatusView can find it (to add the listener).  Everything in the project is created directly by one of the movie clips, and the runtime seems to create these movie clips in an arbitrary order.  For example, say I create a MovieClip symbol called GameView and I create the instance of the Player there, and GameView is the parent of StatusView.  When StatusView is constructed, I'd like to be able to access the Player from it's parent, but at that point GameView hasn't had it's constructor code run yet.  This is true even if I wait for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event.

I could put the game model code in a singleton, but this seems like a hack to me.  Is there a best practices way in Flash that lets me create and access my game model independent of all the MovieClip symbol stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the reference of the Model to the constructor of the View, but are not calling the constructor yourself (because you do not create the object via code) you are out of luck here.

You could instead simply define a method on your View to pass a reference of the Model object:

```
public function setModel(value:Model):void
```

usage:

```
view.setModel(player);
```

There's no "law" that you have to pass the Model to the constructor of the View.
You can also create a set function for convenience:

```
public function set model(value:Model):void
```

usage:

```
view.model = player;
```

I feel like I have to disagree on the Singleton. The purpose of a Singleton is to guarantee that there's only one instance of it in existence. That's it.
It is not there to pass reference around easily (because the method to get the single instance is static). This is (IMO) a bad practice.
You could make anythign static in order to pass it around "easily". But this would make a mess and nobody does that.
But suddenly, just because the singleton pattern uses a static method, a lot of people think it's a clever way to get to the reference. I beg to differ.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could implement Player class as singleton if you need just one instance. I don't think that that looks like a hack (for example, in PureMVC framework each model is a singleton).
At second, you can create instances of Player class in some general class (manager) and send them to views.

P.S. Also, I want to note that you can extend your Player class from EventDisptacher without creating specific field "eventDispatcher" in Player class. I don't know what way is better, but this one is simpler, imho.

Comment: Agree. Have Player extend EventDispatcher.